# Is it possible to create AWS Glue workflow that will run the same job with multiple parameters?

Tags: aws-glue

Looks like I cannot add the same job to a workflow more than once but I need to run the same Glue job multiple times with different parameters. Not possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can always set properties on your workflow and then you can access them in your job as shown in below . Refer to [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/workflow-run-properties-code.html) link for more information.

```
import sys
import boto3
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from pyspark.context import SparkContext

glue_client = boto3.client("glue")
args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME','WORKFLOW_NAME', 'WORKFLOW_RUN_ID'])
workflow_name = args['WORKFLOW_NAME']
workflow_run_id = args['WORKFLOW_RUN_ID']
workflow_params = glue_client.get_workflow_run_properties(Name=workflow_name,
                                        RunId=workflow_run_id)["RunProperties"]

target_database = workflow_params['target_database']
target_s3_location = workflow_params['target_s3_location']
```

Now if you want properties to be changed for every run then you can do the same by using [put_workflow_run_properties](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/glue.html#Glue.Client.put_workflow_run_properties) API call. This can be scheduled to run before your actual job starts it's execution so that the parameters are updated. This API call can be scheduled via lambda or as a part of your workflow which runs before your actual job starts it's execution.

Comment: thanks, but I was asking if I can add multiple instances of the job with various parameters to the same workflow in UI designed. Looks like that is not possible and i have to write a wrapper job/script that will call a job with different parameters

Comment: You can also have multiple of workflows to run concurrently with different set of run parameters

Comment: Hi mishkin. Did you ever found the solution to this problem? Any help would be really appreciated. Thank you

Comment: @mishkin were you able to figure the solution ? I don't want to create duplicate jobs or multiple workflows. Adding same job multiple times with diff parameter on the workflow sounds perfect solution but not working :(

Comment: @SanJ I gave up on workflows, useless and very immature feature. Ended up having a master python Glue job (Python shell type) that will kick off other glue feeding them parameters from a json file. Worked really well

Comment: @mishkin thanks for the reply. I am also working on the wrapper script. With that job reuse approach I am creating ton of logs and difficult to figure which run was for which parameter. How did you handle that ? Do you know a way to rename Job_run_id (jr_**)  ?

Comment: @SanJ my wrapper job only handles 50 or so child jobs and honestly I only look at logs when something fails and the best place is to do this from AWS console. It would be awesome to have consolidated place or something. You should also consider using custom Cloudwatch metrics and build a dashboard there - what what I did to monitor things like duration or record counts for each job that wrapper calls.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is ... sort of.  You can indeed start the same job with different parameters, however in a workflow, assuming you are waiting for the jobs to finish, you cannot identify the job by anything other than its name.  So if you have job `j` that you run with params `--a` and `--b`, then run crawlers afterward, the predicate for the crawler only allows you to specify that you're waiting for job `j`, so cannot distinguish between the two instances.

However, keep in mind that the job is just a container for properties including the the underlying glue script(s) so you can create as many jobs as needed to call the same script with different parameters.  Because they will have different names, this strategy is fine.

But still -- annoying!